# expected better of Sarah

Tags: sentence-meaning, paraphrasing

Which of the following is a proper paraphrase of "I expected better of Sarah"?

> a. I thought Sarah would behave better.

> b. I thought Sarah would have behaved better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say both of OP's alternatives are perfectly acceptable for the cited context, but possibly some pedants might want to argue with the *logic* of that position (because both the speaker's thought and Sarah's behaviour were in the *past* - superficially a better match to OP's *second* version).

In practice, though, few native speakers would think OP's first version was at all unusual. But consider this very similar example...

> 1: *I thought<sup>1</sup> you **would like** him*
> 2: *I thought you **would have liked** him*

...where #1 could be used with ***either*** of the two possible implications *...but actually I was mistaken* OR *...and I was proved right*. But the Perfect form #2 can ***only*** normally be used with first of those two implications *(I thought it **would have** happened, **but it didn't**)*.

It would take a very contrived context for OP's first version to carry the implication that the speaker's expectations had been confirmed (i.e. - that Sarah's behaviour *did* improve). In theory the words *could* have that meaning (as with my alternative), but that would be a very unusual way of expressing it.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that I highlighted ***would like / have liked*** in my examples to draw attention to the different verb forms. But *in actual speech*, heavy stress would be placed on either ***would*** or ***like/liked*** to convey the first possible meaning (speaker acknowledging that he was mistaken). OR heavy stress would be placed on ***thought*** to convey the second sense (speaker triumphantly announcing that his expectations have proved *correct*).

Comment: Upper intermediate and advanced learners perceive a huge difference between the two paraphrases in the original post. "I thought Sarah would behave better" describes the future in the past; it states the speaker's expectation of what was going to happen. On the other hand, "I thought Sarah would have behaved better" describes "past within the past." It says that in the past, the speaker deduced what he thought had (probably) been true. Don't you perceive such a difference?

Comment: Therefore, only a is a proper paraphrase.

Comment: I'm guessing you're not a native Anglophone. I don't precisely understand the point you're making, but it seems to be a matter of logic and/or misguided TEFL principles. I assure you almost all native speakers would see both your alternatives as having equivalent meaning, *in the specific context you describe* (whereas *my* example is subtly different). If you think something different, it's probably because you've been taught how to pass TEFL exams, not how to use English like the natives!

Comment: Suppose you've just been told that Sarah misbehaved last Friday even though you've repeatedly told her to behave herself. Would you say, "I thought she would behave better" or "I thought she would have behaved better"?

Comment: Might I ask you, what is the grammatical meaning "would V" and "would have vpp??

Comment: I'm just gonna end up repeating what I've already said in my answer text. For almost all native speakers, there's effectively *no difference* between using "simple conditional / hypothetical past" ***would behave*** and the Perfect version ***would have behaved*** in your cited context. It's really just a stylistic choice. Where arguably the Perfect version more explicitly references *behaviour that **actually** happened in the past*, as opposed to ***hypothetical** behaviour* (that was *expected*, but didn't actually happen). But in ***my*** very similar example, different assumptions apply.

Comment: Please see this thread https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/would-behave-vs-would-have-behaved.3899576/#post-19949544 . The post by PaulIQ corresponds to the standard understanding of "would V" (on the "future in the past" reading) and "would have vpp" (on the "past within the past" reading).

Comment: I see nothing useful in your link. Any supposed semantic distinction is completely spurious in the cited context. The reference to "backshifting" is just pointlessly confusing here. You might as well try to analyse some difference between *He said his name **is** Smith* and *He said his name **was** Smith* (for most purposes, *there isn't one*).

Comment: Well, the link provides a relatively neat answer, one that conforms to accounts in standard reference works.

Comment: The crucial fact is, it draws our attention to the different times to which "I thought" is relevant as anchors.

Comment: "Bachkshifting" is a common linguistic concept. There's nothing confusing about it.

Comment: There is here! It's totally irrelevant to the *semantics*, so there's no point in bringing it up - which is why I *didn't*, in my answer. Your man  PaulIQ certainly doesn't seem to be helping you to understand English in this particular respect. And I'm now wondering what the point of this interchange might be. Who's teaching who here?

Comment: What matters is not who is teaching who, but whose answer makes more sense. Yours is actually not so useful as it is silent on whether "would have vpp" describes an event prior to the time point established by "I thought." It is in EVERY way relevant to the semantics. I'm wondering why you said the opposite.

Comment: Note the first line of my answer. I think it's safe to say you are one of those pedants who "might want to argue with the *logic* of my position*. I'm simply setting out how the vast majority of native speakers view this supposed "distinction". Which is essentially that *no difference is normally recognised* for your exact context. And I'd also point out that imho writing is just a poor attempt to represent *real **spoken*** language, within which context the *potential* semantic distinction simply can't arise, because it's ***always*** "disambiguated" by heavy stress as per my "note" above.

Comment: You might like to note [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thought+he+would+say%2Cthought+he+would+have+said&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthought%20he%20would%20say%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthought%20he%20would%20have%20said%3B%2Cc0) showing a massive increadse in preference for the "simple past" verb form in recent decades. Obviously that can't reflect such a huge change in the real-world *context*. What it shows is that native Anglophone *writers* are now much more prepared to reflect what people have been *saying* all my life!

Comment: I don't see how the chart supports your position, where the "would V" outnumbers "would have vpp," let alone how it reflects what people have been saying all your life in the particular context in question. At best the chart shows the latter verb form you argue for has been used, a fact I don't object to. But the chart doesn't show the form is properly used in the context under discussion.

Comment: Try googling the two quoted strings **"thought i would do better" "thought i would have done better".** YMMD, but as it happens, the first two results returned on *my* system are this [online quiz1](https://guide.sportsmansguide.com/quiz-can-name-battle-rifles/) and [online quiz2](https://www.nintendolife.com/quizzes/how-well-do-you-know-zelda-breath-of-the-wild). They're completely unrelated websites, but both have a "comments" section, within which ***both of the search terms occur***. I'm talking about ***actual usage***, not what "makes sense" to prescriptivists.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So, if I lay a stress on "thought" I will come across as conveying the idea that I am "triumphantly announcing that my expectations have proved correct"? I.e. "I  thought(stress on "thought") you would have liked him" = "I  thought you would definitely have liked him"="I was sure that when you met him you would definitely like him"="I knew that when you met him you were sure to like him".

Comment: @Eugene: Yes. With *I thought you **knew** that!*, speaker is expressing surprise that you ***weren't*** aware of something up until now, whereas with *I **thought** you knew that!* speaker is asserting that he *already* believed you were aware of the situation (in some context where it's just become apparent that what the speaker thought is in fact correct; the addressee ***did*** already know whatever is being discussed).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you. So, my line is correct? And I can use "would+perfect inf." not only for unrealised actions in the past but for assumptions/presumptions. I.e. "In our excavations at this site we found the remnants of an ancient Egyptian building. They would have belonged to a stall. We are almost sure."

Comment: Yes, when we use *X **would have** happened* in contexts like your preceding comment (instead of plain old Simple Past ***X happened***), it's a way of slightly "distancing" the speaker/writer from the assertion. So arguably it clashes with *We are almost sure* in your exact example, but the usage has become so cliched now that people don't normally even notice things like that. Note that I could in principle "soften" the assertion in my preceding sentence by opting for *...people **wouldn't** normally even notice...* - but as I said, it's so common now that nobody really notices that effect.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Maybe it's a pity that people don't notice it anymore. Strange but as a non-native speaker I hope I do perceive. I am sure that old modality of "will/would" is to be taken as the center if we lay stress on "will/would". If we put down "I think she will=wants/has a strong will to behave better" for the basis,in the past it will be  "I thought she would=wanted/had a strong will to behave better (but she continued not to)".

Comment: The same for "I think she will=wants/has a strong will to have behaved better (by the end of the coming week) - "I thought she would have=wanted/had a strong will to have behaved better" (here there is a mix of the volitional meaning and the Future Perfect).

Comment: But I am not sure whether "would" fully retains its modality when talking about actions to have occurred before the past. I.e. "Her behaviour had been dubious the day we had met and it hadn't changed, that is why after having lived together for a year we decided to split up. - Oh, really, I always thought she would have behaved nicely ever since you had met".

Comment: @Eugene: No native speaker would ever come out with anything like your example there (featuring ridiculous incomprehensible overuse of Past Perfect), so it's not very meaningful to think about any possible difference between *would behave* and *would have behaved* there. (By the time I reached that point in your text, I was just desperately hoping not to see any more of those pesky Perfect forms! :) But the main point of my answer here is that in many/most contexts (including both OP's and your example), the *conditional* Present Perfect and Simple Past may be used interchangeably.

Comment: @FumbleFingers How should it be paraphrased: "Her behaviour ... dubious the day we ... (5 years ago) and it hadn't changed, that is why after ... together for a year we decided to split up (it was 4 years ago). - Oh, really, I didn't know you separated, I thought she would have behaved nicely from the moment you ... her."

Comment: "Her behaviour was dubious [right from] the day we met, and it never changed. That's why after living together for a year we decided to split up". - "Oh, really, I didn't know you [had] separated". If you follow that with "I thought she **would have behaved** well from the moment you met", you mean you ***assume*** (but don't ***know*** for sure; maybe because you never saw her) that her behaviour was always good. If you follow it with "I thought she **behaved** well...", you mean you ***did*** see her, and that's your opinion of her behaviour. As per my *would like / have liked* example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You have really helped me to twig important things.