# Past Simple, Past Perfect or Present Perfect before "which"

Tags: tense, past-tense

Which of the sentences is correct?
I don’t know whether you read my previous messages, which I unsent not long ago, ...
OR
I don’t know whether you had read my previous messages, which I unsent not long ago, ...
OR
I don’t know whether you have read my previous messages, which I unsent not long ago, ...

Comment: I don't recognise this use of ***to unsend***. To me, only the adjectival "past tense" form ***unsent*** is valid. I suppose it's possible some modern electronic messaging systems support a "grace period" after initiating a "send" operation, within which time the pending transmission of the message could be countermanded. Slightly weird concept, though - on a par with trying to use a verb like ***unsay***, or ***uncry***.

Comment: "Unsend" is one of the items in the menu ("Like", "Copy", "Unsend").

Comment: one of the items in ***what*** menu? When I click on "Send" in my Gmail system, the current email is sent immediately. I can't tell how long it takes before that email appears in the recipient's email inbox, or when/if he actually opens it, but even if it was logistically feasible, I find it hard to believe that Google would provide a service to actually remove my email from the recipient's inbox (whether or not he's actually read it).

Comment: Whatever - if you have a context where it makes sense, that's fine. It's not directly relevant to the aspect you're actually asking about here.

Comment: Some social networks have such function, including Instagram. It is certainly impossible to "unsend" an email. Thank you for answering my question so quickly, FumbleFingers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Superficially, OP's Past Perfect example #2 looks invalid, but actually it's syntactically fine. It just requires a context where the current "frame of reference" time is ***already*** in the past. The speaker may know perfectly well that the recipient has read the messages ***by now***, but doesn't know if they'd done so at some specific narrative reference time in the past. That's not a particularly likely context though, obviously.

But as regards the choice between #1 Past Simple and #3 Present Perfect, I'd say this is on a par with [*I thought Sarah **would behave / would have behaved** better*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/307390/expected-better-of-sarah/307394?noredirect=1#comment575955_307394) as asked here recently. Native speakers ***don't normally distinguish*** between these two verb tense forms when referring to "hypothetical / unknown" past situations like this.

Note that ***read*** in example #1 is Past Tense, so it's pronounced ***red*** (don't confuse it with Present Tense, which is *written* the same, but pronounced ***reed***).